# Druid SQL for nested object throwing StringDictionaryEncodedColumn error

Tags: sql, druid, nested-datalist

This is my query

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE("event.data", '$.favItems') as "fav.Items" FROM "db"
```

Where event.data is a nested object with a variety of values and essentially looks like this

```
| event.data                               | 
| {name: "", favItems: [], obj, {}, num: 0 |
```

However, I am getting this error

```
Column [event.data] is invalid type, found [class org.apache.druid.segment.column.StringDictionaryEncodedColumn] instead of [NestedDataComplexColumn]
```

I looked into if there was a way to turn the expr into a JSON value but it looks like it could only become a string so I cannot access within it. Was wondering if there is a way to query for values within or would I have to save it all separately...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you ingest it.
Take a look at some examples where it is declared as a "COMPLEX" data type in the [EXTERN table function here](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/nested-columns#sql-based-ingestion).

You should also be able to use [PARSE_JSON](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql-functions#parse_json) at query time to produce the json object from the string column `event.data`.